# How do I delete images that are not used in the database?

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, codeigniter

I have written scripts that check images in a directory and in a database. I need to delete images in a directory that are not in the database.

How can I do this?

```
   $listingsImages = $this->db->query("SELECT picture FROM product_")->row_array();

   $cwd = './assets/image';
   $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($cwd), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST );


   foreach ( $iterator as $path ) {
       if(!$path->isFile()) continue;
       $dirname = explode("/",$path->__toString());
       $dirname = substr($dirname[count($dirname)-2], 0, 1);
       if ($dirname === ".") continue;
       if (substr($path->getFilename(), 0, 1) === ".") continue;

       if ($path->isDir()) {
           print($path->__toString() . "<br>");
       } else {
           print($path->__toString() . "<br>");
       }
   }

   foreach ($filenames as $filename) {
       if (!in_array($filename, $listingsImages)) {
           unlink($filename);
       }
   }
```

---

```
   $listingsImages = $this->db->query("SELECT picture FROM product_")->row_array();
   //pull out the paths of all used images from the database

   $it = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(base_url('/assets/image/products')); // path to the image folder

   foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($it) as $file) { // go through the folder and pull out the paths to all the files
       $filenames[] =$file->getPathname() . "\n";
   }

   foreach ($filenames as $filename) {
       if (!in_array($filename, $listingsImages)) {
           unlink($filename);
       }
   }
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you getting errors?

Comment: In the first script, I deleted all the images completely, and in the second, an error with the path. But in any case, the scripts don't work.

In your opinion, should one of these scripts work correctly or did I specify something incorrectly?

Comment: Tell me, in the database do you store the full path to the image from the root or just the name? For example: /assets/image/products/img.jpg

Comment: Might be worth a try to remove the newline `. "\n"` from your filenames in the second code

Comment: No, there are only image names in the database, for example: 236534348_847243.jpg

Or rather, I have an array: ["2362482_23724.jpg ", "small287343_8247247.jpg "]

Answer (score 0):

You are closer than you think, correct your second script:

```
$arrImagesFromDB = ['S97A2501.JPG','ikra.JPG'];

$images_folder = './assets/image/products';

$it =  new DirectoryIterator($images_folder); 

foreach ($it as $file) {
    if(!$file->isDot() and !$file->isDir() and !in_array($file->getFilename(),$arrImagesFromDB)){
        unlink( $file->getPathname());
    }
}
```

Comment: I wrote the following code https://codepen.io/andrev_markelov/pen/vYpRYqp But there is a problem with checking, it deletes all files, maybe it compares incorrectly somehow, could you tell me? I also attach a screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/6N2ORnO.png

Comment: @markelov Updated answer with new details. Try again. I checked and the conditions are fulfilled and only those files that are not in the array are deleted.